# How to call and pass c# helper codes from _Layout.CSHTML page in MVC3?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

To force browsers to get latest js and css files in asp.net application, I got the following code. But how can I use this in Layout.cshtml.

I wrote the method in controller and how can I pass to Layout.cshtml in the place of Scripts

```
public static class JavascriptExtension {
public static MvcHtmlString IncludeVersionedJs(this HtmlHelper helper, string filename) {
    string version = GetVersion(helper, filename);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + filename + version + "'></script>");
}

private static string GetVersion(this HtmlHelper helper, string filename){
    var context = helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;
    if (context.Cache[filename] == null) {
        var physicalPath = context.Server.MapPath(filename);
        var version = "?v=" +
          new System.IO.FileInfo(physicalPath).LastWriteTime
            .ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
        context.Cache.Add(physicalPath, version, null,
          DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), TimeSpan.Zero,
          CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        context.Cache[filename] = version;
        return version;
    }
    else {return context.Cache[filename] as string;}
}
```

And then in the CSHTML page:
 @Html.IncludeVersionedJs("/MyJavascriptFile.js")
In the rendered HTML, this appears as:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the namespace of your extension class in the web.config file of the **Views folder**. For example, (Replacing *NamespaceOfJavascriptExtension* with your namespace):

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="NamespaceOfJavascriptExtension" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Then make sure to clean and build your project (You might need to reopen the solution). You should then be able to use `@Html.IncludeVersionedJs("/MyJavascriptFile.js")` in your layout file.

Comment: Now Error shown as 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'IncludeVersionedJs' and no extension method 'IncludeVersionedJs' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You sure you added the correct namespace to the config file in the root views folder? If so, try cleaning and building. You might also need to stop IISExpress (if you have it), or reopening the solution.